# Unable to understand behaviour of "system" function call in C program

Tags: c, system, call

When I run the following program, the output of `system("ls -l")` is displayed before that of `printf`. Why does it happen?

```
#include<stdio.h>  
int main()  
{  
    printf("\nHello world");  
    system("ls -l"); // output of this statement is displayed before that of the preceding 
                     // printf statement
    return 0;  
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `system` is a library function, not a system call. Why do you print the `'\n'` at the beginning of the line rather than at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` is buffered. AFAIK the buffer is written to the output only when a there is a `\n` or when you explicitly flush it (via `fflush(3)`).

So what happens is, `printf` writes the `\n` to the output, then buffers the rest of your string. Then `ls -l` is executed and when your program finishes the buffer is flushed automatically.